# How to fix: Domain name not working in digital ocean's droplet. Using Nginx, docker-compose, django

Tags: django, nginx, docker-compose, digital-ocean, domain-name

I'm trying to set up a domain name to my digital ocean’s droplet. While the IP address works perfectly, the domain name doesn’t seem to do anything and get “This site can’t be reached”.

Checking https://whois.net/ it shows the DNS nameservers are pointing to right direction which are digital ocean’s name servers [NS1.DIGITALOCEAN.COM, NS2.DIGITALOCEAN.COM, NS3.DIGITALOCEAN.COM], and using www.whatsmydns.net it shows the domain name has propagated.

Digital Ocean’s DNS records are the following:

A--domain.tk--directs to X.X.X.X
CNAME--www.domain.tk   is an alias of domain.tk
NS--domain.tk--directs to ns1.digtalocean.com
NS--domain.tk--directs to ns2.digtalocean.com
NS--domain.tk--directs to ns3.digtalocean.com

I’m using a .tk domain using freenom and have configured the same domain nameservers over there.

My NGINX configuration is the following:

```
upstream jaciv_server {

    server djangoapp:8000; 
}

server {

    listen 80;
    server_name domain.tk www.domain.tk;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://jaciv_server;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /static/ {
        alias /opt/services/djangoapp/static/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias /opt/services/djangoapp/media/;
    }
}
```

My docker-compose.yml is the following

```
version: '3' 

services:

  djangoapp:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/opt/services/djangoapp/src
      - static_volume:/opt/services/djangoapp/static
      - media_volume:/opt/services/djangoapp/media
    domainname: jaciv.tk
    networks:
      - nginx_network
      - database1_network

    depends_on:
      - database1

  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.13
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    volumes:
      - ./config/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - static_volume:/opt/services/djangoapp/static
      - media_volume:/opt/services/djangoapp/media
    depends_on:
      - djangoapp
      - redis
    networks:
      - nginx_network

  database1:
    image: postgres:10
    networks:
      - database1_network
    volumes:
      - database1_volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
    networks:
      - database1_network  
      - nginx_network    

  celery:
    build: .
    command: celery -A jaciv_app worker -l info
    volumes:
      - .:/opt/services/djangoapp/src
    depends_on:
      - database1
      - redis
      - djangoapp
    networks:
      - database1_network

  celery-beat:
    build: .
    command: celery -A jaciv_app  beat -l info
    volumes:
      - .:/opt/services/djangoapp/src
    depends_on:
      - database1
      - redis    
      - djangoapp
    networks:
      - database1_network  
      - nginx_network    

networks:
  nginx_network:
    driver: bridge
  database1_network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  database1_volume:
  static_volume: 
  media_volume:
```

My allowed hosts is django setting

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['domain.tk', 'X.X.X.X']
```

Comment: Where is the command that actually runs the Django server?

Comment: ```CMD ["gunicorn", "--chdir", "jaciv_app", "--bind", ":8000", "jaciv_app.wsgi:application"]```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ports for the nginx container in your docker-compose.yml file are off.
You should use:

```
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.13
    ports:
      - 80:80
```

You want the docker proxy to listen on port 80 (the first "80" of "80:80") and want that traffic to be forwarded to port 80 (the second "80" of "80:80") in the nginx container as that's the default port that nginx will listen on.

Comment: Well, as it turns out, I just needed to wait for the 48 hour wait. Nevertheless your remark helped me solved a porting issue. As nginx was listening to port 8000, it had to be specified when searching the URL. I changed this and now everthing works perfect.